# background scroll-y with liquid layout

Tags: css

I have a liquid layout but I am unsure how to get the background to act in the same manner as the content. I have an image which is being created using the scroll-y css call. On full screen it looks great and creates a bordered white box where all the main content goes in and is directly in the middle of the page. However when I resize my window the background image stays in the same place where as all my content is moved to adjust for the window size. Is there anyway to get the background scroll-y image to move in the same liquid style as the rest of the contenyt?

Comment: *"I have an image which is being created using the scroll-y css call."* I have a hard time in visualizing this phrase. Care to post some basic HTML+CSS example which demonstrates the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to create a new wrapper which essentially becomes your new background. Then cut your bg images (ie border and mid) and turn that wrapper into a fluid layout that always takes up the entire viewport. Without knowing what your bg image looks like, this is the best i can recommend to you.